# test if a function accept one or two parameter in configure.ac

Tags: configure, autotools, autoconf

How to test in configure.ac if a given function foo has one or two parameters. I found AC_COMPILE_IFELSE in the documentation but couldn't find an example. and I get always STRING EOF ERROR .
Here is the part where there is an error :

```
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <mistery.h>])],[],[AC_DEFINE([MISTERY_VALUE_ONEPARAM], [42], [The famous answer])])
```

Comment: If you don't know the number of parameters for `foo`, do you at least have any information about the parameter(s) it takes? e.g., `int` types, pointer types, etc?

Comment: In your example you have mismatched square brackets. Not sure if that has to do anything with your error. Check your AC_LANG_PROGRAM( [ [#include <mistery.h> ] ) ] macro call.

Comment: The square brackets wasn't the problem because I fix it after posting this question. IIn fact, the function foo takes one or two parameters and they are both integer. I found a solution anyway . Thanx

Comment: if you found a solution yourself, maybe post it here

Comment: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <mistery.h>]],[[mistery_value(2);]])],[AC_DEFINE([MISTERY_VALUE_ONEPARAM], [42], [The famous answer])],[])

Comment: hummmmmmmm EURECOM Student, softdev class...